# Python 3.10 match/case with constants

Tags: python-3.x, switch-statement, constants, python-3.10

I tried to replace an if/elif/elif/.../else code block with the shorter `match/case` from Python 3.10.
I have three constants defined and want to do something different for each one, so my code looks roughly like this:

```
>>> const_a = 1
>>> const_b = 2
>>> const_c = 3
>>> interface = const_b  # example
>>> match interface:
...     case const_a:
...             print("case a")
...     case const_b:
...             print("case b")
...     case const_c:
...             print("case c")
```

However, when running this code, there will be an Exception:

```
File "<stdin>", line 2
SyntaxError: name capture 'const_a' makes remaining patterns unreachable
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

The `match...case` is more than just a `switch...case`. From https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/#patterns:

> - A **capture** pattern looks like x and is equivalent to an identical assignment target: it always matches and binds the variable with the given (simple) name.
> - A **constant value** pattern works like the literal but for certain named constants. Note that it must be a qualified (dotted) name, given the possible ambiguity with a capture pattern. It looks like Color.RED and only matches values equal to the corresponding value. It never binds.

So you're going to have to create an object that has those variables as attributes and use the qualified names in the match

```
import types

consts = types.SimpleNamespace()
consts.A = 1
consts.B = 2
consts.C = 3

interface = 2

match interface:
    case consts.A:
        print("A")
    case consts.B:
        print("B")
    case consts.C:
        print("C")
```

Which, as expected, prints `B`

For more information on *why*, see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/#alternatives-for-constant-value-pattern

Comment: Thanks! I think it is also possible to use an Enum then, right? However, I dislike the design descision to only allow "qualified" names and not conventional constants.

Comment: conventional constants are disallowed for a reason: that way causes ambiguity with the _capture_ match pattern.

Comment: @mara004 it's possible something similar was [proposed and rejected](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/#id16) or [deferred](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/#id19)

Comment: People have been asking for something like a switch case for 30 years. Now it finally gets implemented and you cant even match a number with constants without a workaround like this. Who cares about all the advanced pattern matching you can do with this if it fails for such a common and simple use case without a workaround like this? This honestly just blows my mind.

Comment: Rule 1: Simple is best.
Rule 2: When simple isn’t possible, it’s not best.