# python match : confusion about match testing

Tags: python

I know there are other ways to do this, but I am want to use `match` here.

In this snip, the `break` piece matches for all integers > 0, but I want it to match only `n`' I'm using the cast because it wasn't working without it. Not working *with* it either but...

```
#times is a simple list of python datetimes

n=len(times)
for i,time in enumerate(times) :
    print(f'{i} {time}')
    match int(i):
        case 0 : 
            print('continuing') 
            continue
        case int(n) : 
            print(f'breaking for {i}')
            #break
        case __ :     
            period = times[i+1] - time
            print(period)
```

Comment: What is contents of times?  ints, datetimes, other?

Comment: The `case` argument is a pattern match. Variables in it are assigned from part of the value that you're matching, they're not used for equality testing. You should use `if/elif/else` for this.

Comment: `case int(n)` means "Match any integer, set `n` to the matched value"

Comment: `i` will never be equal to `n`. `i` will increment from 0 to n-1.

Comment: @Barmar Probably I should but I want to use the match statement -- as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for comments, but I'm no closer to understanding.

But after Pranav Hosangadi solution in [Python 3.10 match/case with constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67181642/python-3-10-match-case-with-constants) I managed to make this work.

```
from types import SimpleNamespace
count = SimpleNamespace()
count.n = len(times)-1

for i,time in enumerate(times) :
    match i:
        case 0: 
            continue
        case count.n : 
            print(f'breaking for {i}')
            break
        case __ :     
            period = times[i+1] - time
            print(period.seconds)
```

I think there must be a less elaborate solution but I don't see it yet.

Answer (score 0):

As @Barmar explained in the comments, you are not matching *the value* of `n`: you are setting `n` to the matched value (in the `match` context).

Try doing

```
case n:
    print(f'breaking for {i} {n}')
```

to see what's happening.

But since the behaviour you expected is true for object properties, and since integers are objects in Python, you may use `n.real` (which despite the name returns an integer type): so change your `case` to:

```
case n.real:
```

This will work.

**EDIT**

Full code, as requested.

Note: since the code uses `times[i+1]` we need to break at `len(times)-1` or we will get a "list index out of range" exception.

```
times = [datetime(2022,10,18), datetime(2022,9,26), datetime(2022,8,12), datetime(2022,12,31)]
n = len(times) - 1
for i,time in enumerate(times) :
    print(f'{i} {time}')
    match i:
        case 0:
            print('continuing')
            continue
        case n.real:
            print(f'breaking for {i}')
            #break #not needed: it will exit anyway
        case _:
            period = times[i+1] - time
            print(period)
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. After Pranav Hosangadi solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67181642/python-3-10-match-case-with-constants , I tried something else. I'll put it as a post

Comment: I can assure you that it works (Py 3.10.8) - I just copy/pasted your code, fixed the double underscore typo, removed the useless `int()` casts, and replaced `n` with `n.real`. Btw this solution and the one you cite are conceptually the same: they both find a way to use an object member instead of a free variable to get the desired behaviour

Comment: I didn't doubt that it worked; I couldn't get it to work (my bad, I was sure) so I went searching furthur. I didn't want to nag. As you point out my code had many weaknesses so... Anyway. Thanks very much. If you post your complete solution I'll give it the tick.

Comment: No problems. I was just trying to make clear the point, that you need a dotted notation somehow to have the structural pattern matching work as you expected it to do